# Inmemory storageMode for multidimensional cubes

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, multidimensional-array, ssas, sql-server-data-tools

With Visual Studio 2013 it is possible set the storage mode for a measure group of a multidimensional cube to InMemory:

[image: Visual Studio 2013 Multidimensional Storage Mode]

But switching an Adventure Works measure group to InMemory throws this error on deployment:
[image: strange powerpivot error]

I have found no useful documentation on this. Any idea how it the InMemory StorageMode is supposed to be used with multidimensional cubes?

Answer (score 0):

InMemory Storage is for Tabular Mode only.

http://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2012/06/tabular-query-modes-directquery-vs-in-memory/

Comment: Yes, tabular can be DirectQuery or In-Memory or combinations of both.
But the screenshots above are from the designer for multidimensional cubes in Visual Studio 2013 SQL Server Data Tools. It is not the same as the designer for tabular models. Why is the InMemory StorageMode option available for Multidimensional cubes?

Comment: I would say it is a bug.